# Persist result of a MEF composition

Tags: c#, serialization, mef

I have complex set of import and export definitions in my program. The composition of them thanks a significant amount of time. Thus, is there any chance to 1) compose a MEF container and then serialize the connections between imports and exports and 2) deserialize these connections to the same composition without the time consuming search. Of course I have to garantee that the set of assemblyies for serialization and deserialization is identical.

Any tip where to start?

Comment: Is it really the composition that is taking a long time and not the building of the container? In my experience, the building of the container is the part that takes the time but I might be wrong.

Comment: I measured it, and "ComposeParts" is the time consuming call

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328243/how-to-persist-mef-import-and-export-information-to-disk?rq=1